# How does one save the entire Picasa database of photos in order to migrate to lightroom?

Tags: troubleshooting, picasa

I'm new here, and am in the same boat as many of you needing to transition photos from Picasa 3 to another photo editor like Lightroom 3. I am still running XP pro on desktop. I have 2 vista notebooks a 32 and 64 both in disrepair.Can't upgrade at this time am financially devastated; suites of photo editing software for XP pro won't run on upgraded OS so you get the picture.

I'd like to migrate my data base of between 1 and 2 TB of edited and non-edited nor even sorted yet photos in Picasa 3 to Lightroom 3. Understand that I need to save my entire data base of picture folders and albums first but have no idea after years of attempting it how to save an entire data base. I think I can save folder by folder but would be doing so from my grave literally.

I'm not as savvy as many of you but understand some of the explanations and suggestions. I really need to accomplish this but baby steps for me and I need explanations of terms in many cases. I don't know if you will have patience for me but I hope to learn here in order to accomplish this. My Picasa 3 is already not working, it's not responding to any tasks although I have figured out how to import new photos, although Google says you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate from Picasa to Lightroom?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/74805/how-to-migrate-from-picasa-to-lightroom)

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly clear what you mean by "save the entire database". If you mean, keep all of the edits you have made, *and* be able to undo them - there are no tools that are available today to do so.

See this answer for what you *can* do: [How to migrate from Picasa to Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/74820/4892).